# Spring transaction issue when transactional method calls non-transactional method

Tags: java, sql, spring, transactions

I have 2 services bean, say, Service A (containing transactional methodA), Service B(containing non-transactional methodB). Both methodA and methodB will insert DB with records. I wonder, if methodB(non-transactional) has an runtime exception, will the insert operation in methodB get rolled back when methodA(transactional) calls methodB(non-transactional)? As I know insertion in methodA will be rolled back.

```
class ServiceA(){
    @Transactional
    methodA(){
       insert record into DB;
       call methodB();
    }
}

class ServiceB(){
    methodB(){
       insert record into DB;
       do something;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one transaction and everything participates in that transaction.

Comment: an easy way to find out is to place a exception in methodB and step through it. Like a division by zero just after the insert